# How to call javascript google map api function correctly?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api

I'm trying to get google maps to show up on my site with Los Angeles being at its center. I am doing so with a javascript google maps api key. I checked the key by downloading platform API checker and it said it's successful. I'm getting an error on the map that "this page can't load google maps successfully." What am I doing wrong below? Thanks!

personInfo.html

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title> Covid 19 Patient Map </title>
    <style>

        #map{
            height: 400px;
            width: 50%;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
<p style="text-decoration: underline;"><a href="http://127.0.0.1:5000"/> Back to home </a></p>
<h2 id="displayName" ></h2>

<div class="block">
    <label>Lives at: </label>
    <p id="address"></p>
</div>

<div class="block">
    <label>Covid status?: </label>
    <p id="covidPos"></p>
</div>

<h1> Covid 19 Patient Map </h1>
<div id="map"></div>
<script>

var personInfoList = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("newList1"));
           for(let item of personInfoList) {
                 document.getElementById("displayName").innerHTML = item[0] + " " + item[1];
                 document.getElementById("address").innerHTML = item[2];
                 document.getElementById("covidPos").innerHTML = item[3];
                   }
                function initMap(){
                 var opts = {zoom: 10, center: {lat: 34.0522, lng: 118.2437}
                    }
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),opts);
                   }
</script>

<script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDzRLuKxf5Xa4oTwp5o_PErnB8u88br3MU&callback=initMap">
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you sure you want to publish your API key here?

Comment: `this page can't load google maps successfully.` - either your API key is wrong, or you're trying to use it on a domain it isn't registered for

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found that the api key you're currently used to is the api key for development purpose only. As the documentation said [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages?utm_source=maps_js&utm_medium=degraded&utm_campaign=billing#api-key-and-billing-errors).

You have to create your own API key [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key?hl=id).

**A little bit suggestion** to not put your api key like that (front-end side), instead of retrieve the key from the back-end (you might want to use .env file).

Comment: ill try what u suggested. I ended up opening the javascript error browser and it told me to enable billing which temp fixed the issue. But again I'll look into doing it the back end way you talked about

Comment: *not put your api key like that (front-end side)* how else will it work? this is why API keys are enabled on particular domains - that way you can publish the API key all you like, it'll only work on the domain YOU allow it to

Comment: Also, how do you know that is a development purposes only key, and not one owned by the OP? Curious to know how you knew that